# Admin Ajax is returning 0

Tags: admin, ajax

I am relatively new to jQuery and AJAX in particular. I have a small issue with the return value always being 0, though I think this is actually the success message and it's not returning anything.

I have scoured the Google-verse and I have the die() function on the PHP callback and I believe the add_actions are correct.

I am working on a local host, though I doubt that affects it and this is all in the admin, not front end. I also checked that the js is enqueued and localised.

I get a 200 OK message in the chrome developer area.

I also tested out the basic AJAX from http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and it also returned 0, which makes me wonder if it is something other than the code outlined below.

Right now I am just trying to make it send something back to the jQuery. Any help would be appreciated.

**The jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.cl_link_buttons').val('id').click(function() {

            var currentid = jQuery(this).attr('id');

            //alert(currentid);
            console.log(currentid);

            jQuery.ajax ( data = {
                action: 'cleanlinks_ajax_get_post_data',
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                "currentid" : currentid

            });

            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

                var dataz = response;
                alert( dataz );
                console.log (dataz); //show json in console


            });

            return false;

    }); //end click event
}); //end doc ready
```

**The PHP**

```
add_action("wp_ajax_cleanlinks_ajax_get_post_data", "cleanlinks_ajax_get_post_data");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_cleanlinks_ajax_get_post_data", "cleanlinks_ajax_get_post_data");

function cleanlinks_ajax_get_post_data() {

$from_ajax =  $_POST['currentid'];

echo "do" . $from_ajax . "something";

die();


}
```

Comment: Have you verified that ajaxurl is set properly?

Comment: Does your browser console show any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: `jQuery('.cl_link_buttons').val('id').click(function()` looks odd.

Comment: Andrew, yes I believe it is correct, the request url in Chrome Inspector is showing domain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: @s_ha_dum No errors showing

Comment: @toscho Perhaps it does look odd, it was the only way I could think of getting the elements ID on click, and it does do the job, the code also shows it has that data, again issue is getting a response from the php.

Comment: See also [how to debug AJAX with HTTP](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96556/73).

Comment: There is no need to `return false`. If using jQuery, use http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I worked it out. It was not the jQuery as such though I have improved that, it was the placement of the call back function. I moved it over to the main plugin file and it worked.

Comment: can you show how did you do it ?

Comment: I am having this same issue, could you show how you fixed this?

Comment: Another answer is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131397
@Jeremy

Answer (score 52):

A `0` response means either that the action is not set (in the ajax data) or that the action's callback function cannot be found.

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct answer. All adding die() to the end does, is terminate the script. That answer is technically correct if you're seeing 0 appended to the END of the output, however if all you get is '0', then it means nothing was returned, and you have an error as described in this answer.

Comment: Or you just returned nothing on purpose in the php that handles the ajax request.  Be sure to echo something out, otherwise, use `.always` to capture it.

Answer (score 32):

What you have to do is add `die();`at the end of your function.

See the reason and more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Notes:

- You should `echo` something before executing `die`. This will prevent server errors, and will help when debugging.

Comment: This is the answer to the WP AJAX 0 problem.

Comment: Actually, if you just add `die()` without echoing something out, this will also give you a 500 Internal Server Error, and return `0` for `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`.  You should always echo out something, even if you are just setting values and nothing is needed to be returned.  Otherwise, if you echo nothing and `die()`, you have to use `.always()` to capture it, cause it will not be in `.done()`, it will be in `.fail()` because it dies without anything = 500 Error.

Comment: do you have some links, or working code, so we can take a look ? @SolomonClosson

Comment: All my answers have been tested in live environments.  It's very simple to test this, just do a `die();` in the ajax function in the `functions.php` file without echoing out anything prior to this, and call the action via ajax, e.g.: `var testing = $.ajax( ... ); testing.fail(function(response) { console.log('Failed ' + response); }); testing.done(function(response) { console.log('Success ' + response); }); testing.always(function(response) { console.log('Ajax Request complete: ' + response); });`

Comment: You will notice, Failed will show up, the response will be a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Than add an echo to the PHP function just before you `die();`, the response will than be the echo'd result.

Comment: I tested this with `dataType` set to `HTML`, not sure if other datatypes return something different tho, or what happens when it is not set, since it will attempt to take an educated guess at the data type.  IMO, it's just best to output something always, even if it's a string that says 'success' or 'failure'.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too, and it was the fact that I was using `return` instead of `echo` in my PHP function. Changing it to `echo` fixed it.

```
function doAjax() {
    $result = getPosts();
    echo json_encode($result, true);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Man! it's working for me))

Answer (score 3):

I got same problem. And solved it. You must send "action" variable like in example:

```
var dataString = {lat: '55.56', lng: '25.35', action:'report_callback'};
 $.ajax({                            
        url: "http://domain.net/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",  
        type: "POST",
        //some times you cant try this method for sending action variable
        //action : 'report_callback',
        data:dataString,        
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log(data);

            },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error");            
        }
    });
```

Because in wp-admin/admin-ajax.php is handler for action variable:

```
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {...}
Line 26
```

Comment: The OP ___does___ send an `action` parameter. While this may have worked for you it was not the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this code on the console

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {action:'cleanlinks_ajax_get_post_data'}, function(response) {
     console.log (response);
});
```

I can see many things wrong about your JavaScript code and that might be the reason.

Comment: Well it is coming up with a lot of things I dont fully understand. What I do understand: ReadyState 4, status 200, responseText "0". 

And then it comes up with the response 0.

If there something in specific I should be looking for here?

If there are issues with the code, please point them out and I can look into them, I am still learning jQuery.

Comment: do you have your site running live?

Comment: No, it's localhost

Comment: Hard to tell. Could you try running console.info(ajaxurl); and see what it gives?

Comment: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php is the response

edit -- 

/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
undefined

Comment: try replacing ajaxurl with 'http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' and see what it gives

Comment: Not a direct solution, but this answer is something one should definitely cross-check for a solution to the OP

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.cl_link_buttons').val('id').click(function() {
       $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action : 'ajax_filter',
                currentid : 'currentid'
            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $result = $(result);
                        $result.fadeIn('7000');
                        $("#showresults").html(result);

            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status) {
                $('#showresults').slideDown('slow')
            }
            });
     });
});
```

//code function php

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_filter', 'ajax_filter' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_filter', 'ajax_filter' );
    function ajax_filter(){
        $date = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : 0;
        echo $date;
        die();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Just posting code is not good, can you please explain what this piece of code does?

Comment: important: $date = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : 0;
And function die();

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, anybody coming from shortcode development, if you are getting a proper response through WordPress Ajax request but a 0 is getting appended, it's only because you are 'echo'ing instead of 'return'ing. Shortcodes are never meant to 'echo' or output anything. Just another scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, to fix it I used [`wp_die()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) at the end of my function just after an `echo`. Don't forget to pass your action on your script.

To be sure, check if your function has to use [`wp_ajax_nopriv`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) like `wp_ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, for anyone who get here googling "ajax request is returning 0":
Remember when you add ajax action to object's method to be sure methods access modifier is `public`.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', [$object, 'my_method']);
```

`add_action` just silences if it can't call your method outside of `$object`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use wp_localize_script() function to set ajax url, admin ajax returns 0. I think it's Wordpress bug. Here's is an example :

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'search_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/search.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );    
    wp_localize_script( 'search_js', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
```

The javascript file (search.js) :

```
    $('#search_input').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: 'action=my_custom_action_search&search_criteria=' + request.term,
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            } 
        });
    },
    minLength: 3
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who get error 0 :), action => 'action'

```
var data = { 'action': 'firmabilgilerikaydet', 'data': form_data };

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) { alert(response); });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using localhost and your php server side code is in a plugin file first login to admin dashboard and refresh the plugin page.  Secondly, check if the plugin is activated.  Then go to frontend and refresh and try sending again.

Answer (score -1):

```
YOU TRY:

add_action('init', 'ly_form_ajax_init');


function ly_form_ajax_init() {
    wp_register_script('ly-form-ajax-script', plugins_url().'/ly-form/js/ly-script.js' , array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('ly-form-ajax-script');

    wp_localize_script('ly-form-ajax-script', 'ly_form_ajax_object', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'redirecturl' => home_url(),
        'loadingmessage' => __('')
    ));
}
// Action is: contact_ajax
add_action( 'wp_ajax_contact_ajax', 'my_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_ajax', 'my_function' );

function my_function(){
    ob_clean();
    echo "http://sanvatvungcao.com";
    wp_die();
}

/**
 * Short code in page like this: [ly-form]
 * @param type $atts
 * @param type $content
 * @return string
 */
function ly_form_shortcode($atts, $content = "") {
    echo html_form_code();
}
add_shortcode('ly-form', 'ly_form_shortcode');

//HTML Form will show,
function html_form_code() {
    $html = "";
    $html.= '';
    $html.= '';

    $html.= '        Họ đệm * ';
    $html.= '        Tên * ';
    $html.= '        Địa chỉ * ';
    $html.= '        Email * ';
    $html.= '        Nội dung * dg';
    $html.= '        ';

    $html.=  '';
    $html.= '';
    $html.= '';


    return $html;
}

AND HERE js (ly-script.js):
( function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Perform AJAX form submit
        $('form.ly-form-ex').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#loading').html('loading...');
            var dataString = {action:'contact_ajax'};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ly_form_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
                data: dataString,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#loading').html(data);
                },
                error: function (errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }

            });
        });
    }); // end ready
} )( jQuery );
```

Hope it is helpful for you,
Best

Comment: You might want to explain the _why_ :)

Comment: The bottom line here may be the ob_clean(); function. You can do and experience

Answer (score -2):

Try adding an `if` statement:

```
function my_function(){
$id = $_POST['variation_id'];

    if(isset($_POST['variation_id'])) { 


//your coded function


die();
}



}// end function
```

Comment: How would that solve the problem? Note the accepted answer and the original code.