# Stumped - Ajax Response Returns 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can't seem to figure it out. No matter what I do, the ajax call keeps giving a 0 response. I've tested my PHP funtion and it works fine but whenever I call it through ajax I receive nothing (only a 0 response). Any help/suggestions is much appreciated.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ldapattr', 'get_ldap_attr');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ldapattr', 'get_ldap_attr');

function get_ldap_attr() {

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    $lanid = $_POST['lanid'];
    $dn = get_site_option ( "ldapServerOU" );
    $usr = get_site_option ( "ldapServerCN" );
    $pw = get_site_option ( "ldapServerPass" );
    $addr = get_site_option ( "ldapServerAddr" );
    $ids = array();
    $ad = ldap_connect ( $addr )
        or die ( "Connection error." );
    ldap_set_option ( $ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 );
    ldap_set_option ( $ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0 );
    $bind = ldap_bind ( $ad, $usr, $pw );
    if ( $bind ) {
        $SearchFor ="cn=".$lanid;
            $result = ldap_search ( $ad,$dn,$SearchFor );
            $entry = ldap_first_entry ( $ad, $result );
            if ( $entry != false )  {
                $info = ldap_get_attributes ( $ad, $entry );
            }
            $comm  = stripos ( $info['manager'][0], ',' );
                // find position of first comma in CN=Mxxxxxx,OU=Users,OU=MCR,DC=mfad,DC=mfroot,DC=org  (directReports field)
            $eq = stripos ( $info['manager'][0], '=' );
                // find position of first =
            $s_lanid = substr ( $info['manager'][0], $eq+1, ( ( $comm-1 ) - ( $eq ) ) );
                //get substring between = and comma... 
            $sup = getLDAPInfo ( $s_lanid, $bind, $ad, $dn ); 
                // get supervisor's info...
    }

    echo json_encode($sup);
    die();
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#empLanId').on('blur', function() {
        var lanid = jQuery('#empLanId').val(),
            data = { action: "get_ldapattr", lanid: lanid};     
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);  
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `ajaxurl` variable? Did you try hard-coding it?

Comment: Surely that code can't be right? That Javascript block is in PHP context and would trigger errors.

Comment: No they aren't nested together.

Comment: Does it return anything at all, at any point? That is, echo something at the top of the script and see if it returns, then move down a couple of lines. Isolate where this fails.

Comment: @shapada : Please [edit] your code so that context is clear.

Comment: My PHP function works fine. It returns an object with the correct data.

Comment: ajaxurl value: nrsdvm01.mayo.edu/forms/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php and when I click on it the pages displays -1

Comment: I get a connection timeout everytime I click your `ajaxurl` link.

Comment: That's because it's an intranet site.

Comment: @shapada are you able to track the request with firebug or other?

Comment: Yeah, the PHP function fires but nothing returns.

Comment: Should I be passing the lanid argument to my function or is it picked up by the $_POST variable?

Comment: by $_POST, @shapada. if you comment all within your PHP function and do : echo json_encode($_POST); what's happen?

Comment: I get a 0 response.

Comment: How would i go about hard-coding the ajaxurl variable?

Comment: I delete my answer because the hooks declaration was fine

Comment: Any other suggestions? I've been trying to debug this for hours....

Comment: console.log( ajaxurl ) prints the right url?

Comment: console.log(ajaxurl) prints nrsdvm01.mayo.edu/forms/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php which if I visit displays -1

Comment: Try this- similar question -http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97502/admin-ajax-is-returning-0

Comment: Still no luck...

Answer (score 3):

Debug it logically.

This code works. I just tested it. This in a theme (I put it in header.php for testing):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var lanid = 'demo';
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php", null); ?>';
    data = { action: "get_ldapattr", lanid: lanid};     
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);  
        }
    });
});
```

And this code in a plugin:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ldapattr', 'get_ldap_attr');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ldapattr', 'get_ldap_attr');
function get_ldap_attr() {
    $sup = "data is ".$_POST['lanid'];
    echo json_encode($sup);
    die();
}
```

What happens when I use both these pieces of code is that I get "data is demo" in the JS console. Which is what you would expect, basically.

So now, you have to determine why this doesn't work for you. I would specifically look at where you have the PHP code located. Is it in a plugin? Is it in the theme's functions.php file? Are you sure that that part of the code is loaded at all for AJAX responses? It won't work if you have the code in a Page Template, for example, because Page Templates don't load when using the ajax handler.

Comment: I'm loading the file through a shortcode. The file is located in the /inc directory.

Comment: It worked! By moving the PHP into a plugin and the jQuery into the header my object was successfully passed. Could you please explain why!? Thanks you so much! You rock!

Comment: I don't really know what "loading the file through a shortcode" means, so let's just go with "your php function was not loaded when the actual AJAX call was being made, so your function never executed when you made the call to admin-ajax.php" as an explanation.

Comment: So I have it working in Chrome but the darn thing won't work in Firefox or IE. Any suggestions on why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on my local WordPress install. Note that I hardcoded the AJAX URL, it will be different depending on your environment.

In theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ldapattr', 'get_ldap_attr');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ldapattr', 'get_ldap_attr');

function get_ldap_attr() {
    $lanid = $_POST['lanid'];
    echo json_encode($lanid);
    die();
}
```

In the page template itself (for example `page.php`):

```
<input id="empLanId" name="empLanId" value="foo" />
```

In JavaScript file being included on the page template above:

```
jQuery('#empLanId').on('blur', function() {
    var ajaxurl = 'http://localhost/wordpress-vanilla-3.5.1/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    var lanid = jQuery('#empLanId').val(),
        data = { action: "get_ldapattr", lanid: lanid};
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Note that I removed any logic that does not have anything to do with WordPress, in order to try isolate the issue. My conclusion is that your WordPress-related code should be fine.

Comment: Just tried it and still 0 response.