# Using AJAX with Forms

Tags: ajax, forms, front-end

I am attempting to validate and submit a form using AJAX in WordPress, however, the response that I am getting is 0.  According to [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), this would seem to indicate that admin-ajax is unable to find the functions that I defined.

What am I doing wrong?

#### Code (Simplified for Demonstration Purposes)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#test-button', function()
    {
        var name = jQuery("#name").val();
        var AdminAJAX = <?php echo json_encode(admin_url('admin-ajax.php')); ?>;
        
        var ajaxparams = {
            action: 'jp_ajax_request',
            name: name
            };

        jQuery.post( AdminAJAX, ajaxparams, function( response )
        {
            alert(response);
        });
    }
}
</script>

<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_jp_ajax_request', 'jp_ajax_process');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_jp_ajax_request', 'jp_ajax_process');

function jp_ajax_process()
{
    echo 'ajax response';
    die();
}
?>

<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <button id="test-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that but you don't need to `json_encode` the admin url and your `add_action` and `jp_ajax_process` should be in a plugin file or your `functions.php` file

Comment: I used json_encode so that I could access a PHP function from my javascript code.  Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Your `add_action()` calls for the AJAX handlers are too late.

Add these hooks earlier, the best action is probably `wp_loaded`:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'register_ajax_handlers' );

function register_ajax_handlers()
{
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_jp_ajax_request', 'jp_ajax_process');
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_jp_ajax_request', 'jp_ajax_process');
}
```

See also: [Debug AJAX](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96556/73).

This code should be placed in a plugin or in your theme’s `functions.php`.

Comment: Thank you!  So after I did your changes and moved the function to my functions.php, it is working.  However, I think that it would  make more sense to have the 'jp_ajax_process' function with the rest of the code for the forms and javascript (in order to keep everything pertaining to that form in a single file).  Is that possible?

Comment: @William You could combine all these function in one class and hook the methods to different actions.