# Using Ajax with a Class file

Tags: ajax, actions, oop

At the moment I have an ajax that works (I get a success [200] response), but having an issue with the action hooks on the response. The JSON object is not coming back, instead **I'm getting a 0**.

I have the die(); after my return so I'm thinking the issue is the hook not working.

I've tried multiple methods within the Class constructor but I'm not sure if this approach is right, I've done it before with a plugin I made, but this is within the **theme**.

### Form.php

*(included in functions.php with `add_action('after_setup_theme')`*

```
public function __construct(){
 // Test #1
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_process_reservation', array( &$this, 'process_reservation' ) );

 // Test #2 
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_process_reservation', &$this->process_reservation ); //with and without '&' before $this

 // Test #3 (this is incorrect)
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_process_reservation', $this->process_reservation );


//If I wrap this with **add_action('init',function(){... *** then it does not load
 wp_enqueue_script('ajax_script',THEME_MODULES_URL.'/Reservations/form.js',array('jquery'),TRUE);
 wp_localize_script( 'ajax_script', 'myAjax', array(
      'ajaxurl'               => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), //don't change this
      'itemNonce'             => wp_create_nonce("ajax_nonce"), //don't change this
  ));
}
```

Just in case it is needed here is the test of my callback function at the moment as well

```
private function process_reservation(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'process_reservation_nonce', 'nonce' );

    if( true )
        wp_send_json_success( 'ok' );
    else
        wp_send_json_error( array( 'error' => $custom_error ) );

}
```

Form data in the XHR console shows both the action and nounce passed

```
action:process_reservation
ajax_nonce:6f155a1e17
```

I've done enough Ajax to know what to expect so I'm pretty sure its a hooking issue here, perhaps something with the theme scope that I don't understand, either way any suggestions or help from the community would be great! Thanks in advance

Comment: See [debugging AJAX](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96556/73). Tried that?

Comment: I just did thank you. I got a response as expected:

`X-Debug-Ajax-1:File "C:\...\wp-content\themes\bp\functions.php" was called on an AJAX request.`
`X-Debug-Ajax-2:Function "t5_debug_test" was called and the user is not logged in.`
`X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN`
`X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.7`
`X-Robots-Tag:noindex`

I don't think its an ajax issue, thinking just the action hook not firing.

Comment: Maybe because the callback method is set to private? Any difference if `process_reservation()` is public? Just guessing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that **in my functions.php I was loading a file** (*reservations.php*) using the `after_setup_theme` hook

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'init_cpts');
```

And then from within the file that was loaded I was requiring my class files with the `init` hook. I thought this would be ok since `init` loads after `after_setup_theme`, it looked like this"

```
function load_classes(){
    require_once( PATH_TO_FILE .'/Class.php');
}
add_action('init','load_classes');
```

The problem as mentioned in @brasofilo thread was that any action hook I attempted once in the class file would no longer work, because at this point the `init` had already been triggered.

To fix this I simple removed the loaded_classes() as shown above, and instead just `required_once` within the file itself (which is loaded `after_setup_theme`). Then *@brasofilo answer worked like a charm so make sure to +1 his response.*

Comment: How about upvoting his response yourself? ;)

Comment: I tried, my reputation is too low (11) needs to be at 15. So once I get a few more rep points I will. Thanks  @JohannesPille

Comment: Makes sense. :)

Answer (score 24):

The errors I've spotted in your code:

One was pointed by @helgatheviking [in a comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106427/using-ajax-with-a-class-file#comment147925_106427): the Ajax callback has to be a `public` method, not `private`.

Not sure how are you initializing this class, but `wp_enqueue_script`&`_style` (in singular) has to be encapsulated inside a `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook (WP_DEBUG dumps a notice).

You can drop the `&` from `$this`, that's PHP 4. Follows a working example:

```
class MyTheme
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'aux_function' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'init_plugin' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_process_reservation', array( $this, 'process_reservation' ) ); 
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_process_reservation', array( $this, 'process_reservation' ) );
    }

    public function aux_function()
    {
        echo '<h4><a href="#" id="wpse">TEST AJAX</a></h4>';
    }

    public function init_plugin()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 
            'ajax_script', 
            plugins_url( '/test.js',__FILE__ ), 
            array('jquery'), 
            TRUE 
        );
        wp_localize_script( 
            'ajax_script', 
            'myAjax', 
            array(
                'url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( "process_reservation_nonce" ),
            )
        );
    }

    public function process_reservation()
    {
        check_ajax_referer( 'process_reservation_nonce', 'nonce' );

        if( true )
            wp_send_json_success( 'Ajax here!' );
        else
            wp_send_json_error( array( 'error' => $custom_error ) );
    }
}
new MyTheme();
```

**test.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{
    $('#wpse').click(function(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            action: 'process_reservation',
            nonce: myAjax.nonce
        };

        $.post( myAjax.url, data, function( response ) 
        {
            $('#wpse').html( response.data );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So using your example here I got this to work, but then when I started converting it 1 piece at a time I run into issues, again with the hooks. For example, the `add_action( 'init', function() {` wrapper around the `wp_enqueue()` breaks; only when I remove that does the script get enqueued. The only difference I see in your example is yours is inside functions.php file, but my example is in a separate file included in a `add_action('after_setup_theme', 'load_class_file');` inside functions.php

Comment: For example, at the moment in my `__contructor()` even something simple like your `add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
          echo '<h4><a href="#" id="wpse">TEST AJAX</a></h4>';
      });` doesn't work unless I remove the `add_action` wrap

Comment: @Xtremefaith, I've re-written the code to be PHP 5.2 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ajax call

if you use make sure you put dataType : "json"

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

or use `$.getJSON()` function ...

Hope this fix the issue.

Comment: This is not the issue, ajax is being called and getting a response of 200 as expected. But no action is being called, hence returning 0 from the die(0) in the admin-ajax.php