# Stop/Pause WordPress Heartbeat using Javascript

Tags: front-end, heartbeat-api

I use the WordPress heartbeat to check a setting on my server from the front-end. If that setting has a specific value I want to stop bothering the server. There for I want to stop/pause the heartbeat. There are no other things depending on the heartbeat.

I found *wp.heartbeat.stop()* [over here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112426/why-is-admin-ajax-reloading-my-page), but it doesn't work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(document).on('heartbeat-tick', function (e, data) {
        [...]
        if (true == x) {
            wp.heartbeat.stop();
        }
        [...]
    }

});
```

I get this error in the console:
TypeError: wp.heartbeat.stop is not a function
wp.heartbeat.stop();

Can't find the stop() function in the heartbeat.js file.

This code doesn't produce an error, but doesn't work too.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(document).on('heartbeat-tick', function (e, data) {
        [...]
        if (true == x) {
            $(window).trigger('unload.wp-heartbeat');
        }
        [...]
    }

});
```

Do I trigger the *unload.wp-heartbeat* event the wrong way?

Comment: Sincerely good luck with this. I looked at it before and it's an abomination of an API, that got turned upside down along the way and has plenty of now incorrect info about.

Comment: The only thing I got working to ameliorate this was setting the minimal interval to the maximum 10 minutes: `add_filter( 'heartbeat_settings', function ( $settings ) { $settings['minimalInterval'] = 600; return $settings; } );`

Comment: Would have suggested you try `jQuery(window).trigger( 'unload.wp-heartbeat' )` but strangely that does nothing. Perhaps you can workout why?

Comment: I cannot find any documentation of the heartbeat api. That's sad.

Comment: You can help write the documentation here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_heartbeat_settings

Answer (score 1):

Drivingralle,

You are on the right trail here with your code.

I've done some work in the JavaScript console, and my conclusion from debugging `heartbeat.min.js` temporarily (source came from `heartbeat.js`) is that settings.suspend **is** properly triggered on the 'unload.wp-heartbeat' event.  However, I believe it to be a bug that the `focused()` function sets settings.suspend back to false whenever the page is focused.

You could submit a bug indicating that the settings.suspend variable is inadvertently reverted in the `focused()` function after the `unload.wp-heartbeat` event is triggered and/or you could modify the `heartbeat.(min).js` code accordingly, perhaps including a new custom variable settings.permanentlySuspend that is then checked along with settings.suspend in the function `scheduleNextTick()`.

Hope that helps,

Ryan

Comment: I saw this in the heartbeat.js file at line 631:
`case 'long-polling':`

Does that get us further?

Comment: @Drivingralle Not sure it does. You want to stop polling altogether. I think the only options are still to a) submit a bug or b) hack the heartbeat.js code so that the `focused()` function does not un-suspend anything. The lightest footprint if you go with option b is probably to create the settings.permanentlySuspend option that also gets set whenever you trigger the `unload.wp-heartbeat` event.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i was also looking for same solution.

So i have this chat application and i am using polling kind of activity using heatbeat now if when chat closes i don’t want any traffic on my site which is useless so i want to disable heartbeat but unfortunately wordpress do not allow to disable heartbeat, I see it was security reason, There was this stop function before, but they removed.

We have settings option in `wp.heartbeat` where suspend variable is stored but it is not accessible. these are the methods that are accessible using `wp.heartbeat`.

```
connectNow: r()
dequeue: w(a)
disableSuspend: s()
enqueue: u(a,b,c)
getQueuedItem: x(a)
hasConnectionError: q()
hasFocus: p()
interval: t(a,b)
isQueued: v(a)
```

so all i can do is slow down the ajax calls using `wp.heartbeat.interval( 120 );`
where 120 is max time we can set which is about 2 min.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, yet I needed and than found a solution a few weeks back. Unfortunately most of the methods of the heartbeat class are private and not exported, which is quite quite ugly design and I didnt want to modify the heartbeat.js file.

But what you can do using jQuery: Check when a heartbeat AJAX request is about to fire, like so

```
let do_heartbeat = true;
let num_beats = 0;
let abort_heartbeat_after_beat_count = 3;
jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings ) 
{
    var ajax_req_settings = settings;
    var data = new URLSearchParams(decodeURIComponent(ajax_req_settings.data));
    if(data.get('action') == 'heartbeat') 
    {
        // Example for general heartbeat pause:
        if(!do_heartbeat || num_beats >= abort_heartbeat_after_beat_count){
            xhr.abort(); 
            return false;
        }        
        
        // Example: Abort if Tab not focused / active
        if(document.hidden || data.get('has_focus') == false) {
            console.log('Tab not focused or user became inactive -> Abort Heartbeat');
            xhr.abort(); 
            return false;
        }
        
        num_beats++;
        
        // Example code on how to control / change the interval, e.g. to make heartbeat slower after 
        // a specific number of heartbeats, in this example making it get slower after 2 beats
        if(num_beats > 2) {
            wp.heartbeat.interval(120);
        }    
    }
});
```

You can do a lot of cool stuff taking this route.

In this case, you could change `let do_heartbeat = true;` within some other script / logic and thereby pause / resume the heartbeat. Or as shown, you could let the heartbeat only run a specific amount of times and than abort it and/or make it slower. Whatever you prefer